# Dictionary is not safe if i only need to read values in threaded application?

Tags: c#, .net

I already have a initialized and filled Dictionary class i read values as below.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static Dictionary<string,object> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public object Get(string key) 
    {
        return Dictionary[key];
    }

    public List<object> Get(object type) 
    {
        return Dictionary.Where(d=>d.Value == type);
    }
}
```

As you can see that I have only 2 case that i just read values. If there is no any bad side effect in threaded app about above code so i will prefer to use Dictionary instead of using ConcurrentDictionary because of better performance.

Comment: There are no race conditions in read only scenarios.. every thread will read the same values. Does this dictionary change at all? If so.. then you should consider `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: No Dictionary will not change and object references also will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems arise when threads are modifying the dictionary.

For example, at the same time, `thread a` is reading from the dictionary while `thread b` is changing some values. `Thread a` will get some changed values in his read.

In your case, you are always reading from the Dictionary so you will have no issues.

Answer (score 1):

In theory this is fine, however this is not thread safe because you leave a public reference to the Dictionary via the property.  It just depends on how paranoid you want to be in terms of protecting yourself from potential side effects down the road.  Even if you pass a reference to the Dictionary into the constructor of my object and refer to is a private in the wrapping class, you still need to deep copy this parameter so that if the caller later modifies the Dictionary its keys/values are not mutated inside your wrapping class.

So as long as you're careful, your solution will work.  You are leaving yourself open to potential thread safety issues however.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threaded management is for resoling race conditions and conflicts during the *changing* of the data (updating and writing) but for simple reading, if before you jump into the multi-threading  you already done with with dictionary construction, you can avoid manage multi-threaded access.